# Error in extracting the data from textfile and multiply them

Tags: c#

I have two matrices.the first matrix(text file 1) is (89359,100) and the second one (text file 2)is(100,1143600).
I have to read and extract the first and third column from each of them.
if we assume that `I` is the value of first column of first dataset and `J` is the value of first column of second dataset, `a[I]` is the value of third column of first dataset AND `b[J]` is the value of third column of second dataset. I must calculate the `c[I,J] = a[I] * b[J]` and put them in a matrix.

I have 3 questions :
1- The logic of the code is correct?
2- how can I initialaize the size if matrix c?
3- Error " the name l, k don't exist in current context" at line `c[i, l] = a[i, j]*b[l, k]`. BTW, I tried to define them at the begining of the code as public vaiables.

the format of data in both textfile:

```
0  1     -0.054558254
0  2     0.056978985
0  3     0.681467788
.  .     .........
.  .     .........
.  .     .........
0  100   0.976464969
1  1     -0.787895908
1  2     0.897567
.............
```

the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace doti
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string linei, lineu;
            float[,] a = new float[89395, 100];
            float[,] b = new float[1143600, 100];
            float[,] c = new float[89395, 100];
            StreamReader fileu = new StreamReader("c:\\first.txt");
            StreamReader filei = new StreamReader("c:\\second.txt");

            for (int x = 0; x <= 89395; x++)
            {
                lineu = fileu.ReadLine();
                string[] values = lineu.Split(' ');
                int i, j;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    i = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                    j = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                    a[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(values[2]);
                }

            for (int y = 0; y <= 1143600; y++)
            {
                linei = filei.ReadLine();
                string[] valuesi = linei.Split(' ');
                int l, k;
                foreach (string value in valuesi)
                {
                    l = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[0]);
                    k = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[1]);
                    b[l, k] = Convert.ToSingle(valuesi[2]);
                }

            }
            c[i, l] = a[i, j]*b[l, k];
            var allValues = c.OfType<float>();
            using (var filestream = new FileStream("Dot_Production.txt", FileMode.Create))
            using (var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream))
              {
                foreach (float valuec in allValues)
                    streamwriter.WriteLine(valuec);
              }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: You are creating huge matrices and cause the machine to run out of memory...

Comment: c is about 817527619200 bytes big

Comment: May I ask why you multiply 2 so big matrix?

Comment: since i need the result in shape opf matris.You don,t have any idea?

Comment: I have alot of ideas. You don't make it easy to help you. You want so calculate 10e11 numbers and hold it all in memory. thats way to much for a .net program where you can use 2GB (about 2e9 byte). If you say what the multiplication is for perhaps there is a way of opimisation.

Comment: I only want to multiply the numbers of two matrices that I wrote above the format and get the result in matris or any format. it can be a list or any thing else. @MartinHoratschek

Comment: Ok you still don't say WHY you want to do that. Sorry I can't help you when you dont give more information. Sad that its one of the many questions here where the asker is not helping the answerer!

Comment: It was an sparce matris that by some methods I seperated it to two matrices with add one demensional (k).And now, if i can multiply these two matrices, the missing data become peredictable. The results are complete scores that must be sorted ascending. hope it can help @MartinHoratschek

Comment: Perhaps you mix up things. From where are these numbers? Could it be, to example, a *file size* instead of actual number of items? Shouldn't you count *lines* first? What is this `100` value?

Comment: 100 is the column number of first matrix and also the row number of second one. I must read the lines since to fetch the numbers @Sinatr

Comment: @user3280040 Sparsity is something to be treasured and preserved. You appear to have thrown it away. Don't do that.

Answer (score 9):

You are indeed out of memory. Your matrix is 761GB in size.

Calculate its size by multiplying the two dimensions by the size of the element. In this case that is 89359*1143600*8 which is 817,527,619,200 bytes.

Even if you could allocate matrices of that immense size, it would take an age to perform arithmetical operations on them.

You want to multiply A and B where A is 89359 by 100 and B is 100 by 1143600. How many floating point operations are needed? There are 89359*100*1143600 multiplications/addition operations to perform. That is a total of 20,438,190,480,000 floating point operations.

You are going to need to find a more clever solution to whatever your problem is. For instance, is there any sparsity in your matrices that you can take advantage of?

Comment: what a bout the logic? is it correct?and how can i solve the problem. any way?

Comment: Beat me to it! 89359 x 1143600 x 8 bytes

Comment: To handle such huge matrices you would need to use an entirely different way of doing things. For example, you have to keep the data on the disk and only load a small bit of it in the memory (i.e. variables)

Comment: @luiges90 ... or invest in some more RAM ;-)